# How to update deep list in ImmutableJS?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Can anyone tell me what how to update 'value' by id in this structue in ImmutableJS?

```
map = {
  list: [
    {
      id: 1,
      value: 'update'  
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. However, it is not the best solution, because that will search all items in the list. If you can change your structure instead of `List` you can use `OrderedMap`.

```
var newData = map.set("list", map.get("list").map(data => data.get("id") === 1 ? data.set("value", "updatedValue") : data));
```